# How to find the matrix representation $[T]_S,_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$B=\{x-x^2,1+x,1-x^2\}$ is a basis for $P_2$. Also, define T: $P_2\to P_2$ by $$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)=-a_0-a_2+(a_0+a_1)x+a_1x^2$$

My question is how to find the matrix representation of $[T]_S,_B$ where s is the standard basis.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we have the basis $B = \{ \underbrace{x-x^2}_{e_1},\,\underbrace{1+x}_{e_2},\, \underbrace{1-x^2}_{e_3}\}.$ The first thing we need to do is to express every transformed element of the basis $S=\{1,x,x^2\}$ in terms of the elements of basis $B$. Thus, we have:
$$T( 1 ) \begin{array}[t]{l}= T(1+0x+0x^2) = -1 - 0 + (1+0)x+0x^2= -1 + x = 1(x-x^2)-1(1-x^2) \\
= 1e_1 + 0 e_2 -1 e_3.
\end{array} $$

The coefficients are going to form the first column of the transformation matrix, i.e.
$$[T]_{S,B} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0 & * & * \\ -1 & * & *  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Similarly, we have that:
$$T(x)\begin{array}[t]{l} = T(0+1x+0x^2) = 0 - 0 +(0+1)x+ 1x^2 = x+x^2= 1(1+x) -1(1-x^2)\\=0e_1 + 1e_2 -1e_3.
\end{array}$$

I guess now you can continue and find the second column of the transformation matrix and following the same procedure we can complete our matrix by finding the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You have $B=\{x-x^2,1+x,1-x^2\}$ and $S=\{1,x,x^2\}$. 
In order to obtain the matrix representation of $[T]_S,_B$, we will evaluate $T(v)$ for each vector $v$ of the basis $S$ and express it with vectores of the basis $B$.

$$T(1)=T(1+0x+0x^2)=x-1=(x-x^2)-(1-x^2)$$
$$T(x)=x+x^2=-(1-x^2)+(1+x)$$
$$T(x^2)=-1=-\frac{1}{2}[(x-x^2)-(1-x^2)-(1+x)]$$

Finally :
$$[T]_{S,B} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ -1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}$$